# INSERT triggers with 'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING'

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-insert, upsert

I have an `INSERT` statement in Postgres 9.5+, but the INSERT sometimes doesn't actually happen because of a key conflict (I've set `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` on the INSERT).

If the `INSERT` happens, then of course the trigger runs. But if the `INSERT` doesn't happen because of a key conflict, will triggers still run?

Does it depend on whether it's a `BEFORE` or `AFTER` trigger?

Comment: The `insert` trigger will not run, because there is no row to run on.  If you did an `update`, then an update trigger would run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per-row **`BEFORE INSERT`** triggers are fired, and possible effects on the proposed row applied, before checking for conflicts. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> Note that the effects of all per-row `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are
> reflected in excluded values, since those effects may have contributed
> to the row being excluded from insertion.

A plain `INSERT` would raise an `EXCEPTION` because of the unique violation, and that rolls back everything (except what cannot be rolled back, like incrementing a sequence).

But the UPSERT with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` suppresses the exception, hence the effects of any such triggers persist, even if the row proposed for insertion is skipped.

(Consequently, when using `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`, effects of such triggers are reflected in the special `EXCLUDED` row that's visible in the `UPDATE` part.)

But **`AFTER INSERT`** triggers are not even fired for either case. The row is never actually inserted - with or without raising an exception.

---

I thought of using a [`RULE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) instead, which can rewrite an `INSERT` to run additional commands, independent of the outcome. More tricky than a trigger, but it kicks in *before* the `INSERT` might be cancelled. ***However***, [the manual warns:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html)

> Note that an `INSERT` containing an `ON CONFLICT` clause cannot be used on
> tables that have either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` rules. Consider using an
> updatable view instead.

So, no dice.

Comment: @user779159: My original answer was incorrect. Consider the rewrite.