# postgres INSERT trigger fires even with ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In a couple of SO answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435016/5578790), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40731729/5578790)), it's suggested that `INSERT` triggers shouldn't fire if there's a conflict and `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is in the triggering statement. Perhaps I've misunderstood, but it does not seem to be true in my experiments.

Here's my SQL, run on Postgres 9.6.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
        n text PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE FUNCTION def() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Called def()';
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER deftrig BEFORE INSERT ON t FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE def();
```

If I then run a couple of inserts:

```
testdb=> insert into t (n) values ('dummy') on conflict do nothing;
NOTICE:  Called def()
INSERT 0 1
testdb=> insert into t (n) values ('dummy') on conflict do nothing;
NOTICE:  Called def()
INSERT 0 0
```

I would have expected to see `Called def()` the first time, but not the next.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger runs before the conflict check. The trigger has an opportunity to change the inserted values, and it wouldn't make sense to check for collisions before this happens. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> Note that the effects of all per-row BEFORE INSERT triggers are reflected in excluded values, since those effects may have contributed to the row being excluded from insertion.

An `AFTER INSERT` trigger will behave as you expect.